# How to make WorkManager.cancel() immediate?

Tags: android-workmanager

I have duplicated data backednd side due to the fact that WorkManager.cancel() isn't immediate.

I tried to maked the cancellation immediate by making it a Single. but it doesn't work.

```
private fun cancelSendEventsWorkManager(): Single<Boolean> =
            Single.fromCallable {
                WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).getWorkInfosByTag(SendEventstWorker.TAG).cancel(true)
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

and use it like this on a *click button event* :

```
Single.concat(
                                cancelSendEventsWorkManager(),
                                eventsViewModel.reportAllEvents(),
                                eventsViewModel.saveReportCompleted(),

.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnSubscribe {
                        EventBus.post(ShowProgress(getString(R.string.common_dialog_progress_generic)))
                    }
                    .doOnError {
                        EventBus.post(DismissProgress())
                        listener?.showUnknownErrorDialog()
                    }
                    .doOnComplete {
                        onReportAllEventAndCloseSessionSuccess(userName)
                    }
                    .subscribe(
                            {
                            }, {
                            onReportAllEventAndCloseSessionSuccess(userName)
                        }
                    })
```

**SendEventstWorker**

```
class SendEventstWorker constructor(context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : RxWorker(context, workerParameters) {
   

    private val db: RpxDatabase = RpxDatabase.getInstance(context)
    private val eventRepository: EventRepository

    init {
        eventRepository = db.eventRepository
    }

    override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        // Get the input
        val userId = inputData.getString(KEY_USER_ID)

        return eventsRepository
                .getAllventsByUserId(userId)
                .flattenAsObservable {
                    Log.d(TAG, it.size.toString())
                    it
                }
                .concatMapSingle {
                    val event = it


                    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
                    val typeRef: TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>> = object : TypeReference<HashMap<String, Any>>() {}
                    val map: Map<String, Any> = mapper.readValue(Event.data, typeRef)


                    reportingApi.reportEvent(e.eventventType.getValue(), event.id,
                            event.eventCreateDate, event.bId, event.bHash,
                            map)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .doOnSuccess {
                                deleteEvent(event)
                            }
                            .doOnError {

                            }
                }
                .toList()
                //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { Result.retry() }
                    .onErrorReturn {
                    Result.retry()
                }
    }


    private fun deleteEvent(event: Event) {
        Single.fromCallable { eventRepository.deleteEvent(event) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to acheive the immediate cancelation properly ?

Comment: Is your network request cancellable? There is a lot of code missing here that could cause the problem. Please add your network request code, and how you subscribe to your Singles to your question.

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer done, please lemme know if something is missing.

Comment: This may be a problem: `.onErrorReturn { Result.retry() }`. When you cancel your worker it will most likely throw an `InterruptedIOException` or something similar, but then you are telling your worker to retry.

Comment: I checked the `cancel` return value and found that it return `true'

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: by `cancel` I meant `cancelSendEventsWorkManager()`

Comment: OK that's good, but it's not relevant to my comment above. You are retrying so the request might start again after you cancel. Print the error inside `.onErrorReturn` to check

Comment: Ok I see your point now. I will check that ASAP and let you know.